# iOS -- Can I access a user's Books library?

Tags: ios

I know it's possible to access and play a user's iTunes library. Is there any comparable access to the user's books library? I'm guessing no, but figured I'd check just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to access this information (on iOS <= 6.1.3). The Books application is a stand-alone app with its own private sandbox where it stores the books.